# Why do I get this PHP Warning: "setlocale(): Specified locale name is too long"?

Tags: php, centos

When I run this script:

```
<?php
$old_locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, '0');
setlocale(LC_ALL, $old_locale);
```

I get:

```
PHP Warning:  setlocale(): Specified locale name is too long in /tmp/loc.php on line 3
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /tmp/loc.php:0
PHP   2. setlocale() /tmp/loc.php:3
```

If I also print `$old_locale`, it looks like:

```
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
```

I guess the most basic "why" is that I'm trying to pass in a locale string that is indeed too long. In `ext/standard/string.c` I see:

```
if (Z_STRLEN_PP(plocale) >= 255) {
    php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "Specified locale name is too long");
    break;
}
```

PHP version:

```
PHP 5.4.13 (cli) (built: Mar 15 2013 11:27:51) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

Operating system: up-to-date CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

Output of running `locale` from the command line:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I encountered this PHP warning while working with [Goodby, CSV](https://github.com/goodby/csv/blob/master/src/Goodby/CSV/Import/Standard/Lexer.php#L60).

Comment: The manpage clearly states that an `E_DEPRECATED` notice is thrown if you pass in a string for the category. make sure you've got all the php debug facilities turned on: display_errors/error_reporting/etc...

Comment: @MarcB `LC_ALL` is a constant (int), not a string.

Comment: woops, sorry, I mean the second parameter. the actual $locale. On your second call, that's an over-long string.

Comment: I submitted a patch to goodby/csv. https://github.com/goodby/csv/pull/13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of set local is either a string or an array, i think you will have to seperate your $old_locale for it to work:

```
<?php
$old_locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, '0');
$bits = explode(';',$old_locale);
$loc = array();
foreach($bits as $bit) {
   $value = explode("=",$bit);
   $loc[] = $value[1];
}
setlocale(LC_ALL, $loc) ;
```

Comment: Ah, of course, I should have read http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php more thoroughly. I see that folks used `explode()` in the comments. Thank you! I'll test this and accept your answer if it works (seems like it should).

Comment: Can you not just do this instead of the loop? `parse_str(str_replace(';', '&', $old_locale), $loc);`

Comment: I didn't know you could do that @cryptic thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

```
$old_locale = explode(";", $old_locale);
$old_locale = $old_locale[0];//returns LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
$old_locale = explode("=", $old_locale);
$old_locale = $old_locale[1];//returns en_US.UTF-8
setlocale(LC_ALL, $old_locale);
```